# PDF characters missing in Atril and Evince, but present in xpdf and Chrome

Tags: fonts, pdf-reader

I generate PDF's with `groff` and `ps2pdf`. However, some characters are missing when displayed with `atril` or `evince`:

[image: missing character in evince]

While, in `xpdf` or Google Chrome, they display correctly:

[image: image in xpdf]

Which is odd. When I use atril on the ps-version of the document, it displays the cup correctly.  On other systems (Salix, Mint, Slackware), the cup displays correctly, but not on all. There does not seem to be a relation between the distribution and the display of the cup.

I have installed most fonts (excluding some chinese, japanese etc), but that does not seem to help. I'f re-installed atril (after adding the fonts), but no cup.

Embedding the fonts in the PDF file does not help either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is unknown; nobody advanced an answer.

However, after removing the package `atril-mate` and upgrading atril the fonts came back. What is odd, because they came back in Evince as well. And I did not upgrade Evince.

Bizar, but it works now.